# Loading chunks of data into .json (or dictionary) in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary, python-requests

I want to stream download a .gz file with requests and simultaneously unzip the streaming file.

The code bit I have come up to do that is:

```
import requests
import zlib

url = "https://something"
d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):  
        data = d.decompress(chunk)
```

I also want to convert the chunks of uncompressed data into json/ dictionary. However, as the chunked portion of the data is not guaranteed to be of complete json/ dictionary format, I cannot load the data into dictionary or in json format. Then, I want to send the data bits to a pipeline that will insert the data into a mongodb database.

I want to do something like:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import zlib

url = "https://something"
d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):  
        data = d.decompress(chunk)

        #something like the line down there
        yield json.load(data)

        #or something like 
        yield df.to_dict(data)
```

Is there anyway to load these uncompressed chunks into json or convert them into dictionaries? Or, some other way to load this data into mongodb?

Just for reference, my compressed file is around 90MB and the uncompressed file is about 1.2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

*my compressed file is around 90MB and the uncompressed file is about 1.2 GB*

If you are allowed to use external modules I suggest taking look at [json-stream](https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/) external module, as

> Unlike `json.load()`, `json-stream` can *stream* JSON data from a
> file-like object. This has the following benefits:
>
> - It does not require the whole json document to be into memory    up-front
> - It can start producing data before the entire document has finished    loading
> - It only requires enough memory to hold the data currently being    parsed

As `json_stream.loads` excepts file-like object you need to use `io.StringIO` if you want to load from memory, consider following example

```
import io
import json_stream
data = '["uno","dos","tres"]'
data_io = io.StringIO(data)
for i in json_stream.load(data_io):
    print(i)
```

output

```
uno
dos
tres
```

Note that `io.BytesIO` and `io.StringIO` might be also used in other places where file-like is expected, not only in `json_stream.load`. `io` is built-in module, consult [`io` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However there's one problem, when I pass the bytes it's throwing the following error:
"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' ".

After I pass the data through decode('utf-8') I am getting the following error:
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' ".

And seems like json_stream does not have loads module.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShahriarTasnim I edited my post to show how to work with JSON from memory

Comment: Thank you very much. It did not work for me though. I have created a custom function and used json.loads to load it. But I will try to make it work when I get the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem which is working for me but not sure if it will work for anyone else. Thought I'd share it here just in case.

```
import json
import requests
import zlib

url = "helloworld.com"
data = ""
flag = 0
d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):  
        datum = d.decompress(chunk)
        try:
                data+= datum.decode('utf-8')

                if flag == 1:
                        data = data[data.find('"first_key"'):]
                        data = "[{" + data
                        flag = 0



                if data.count('"first_key"')>=2:
                #here -8 to get the last instance of the first_key of an element, might change depending upon the format
                        location = data.rfind('"first_key"')-8 
                        data1 = data[:location]
                        if data1[0] == "[":
                                data1+="]"
                        data2 = json.loads(data1)
                        data = "[{" + data[data.rfind('"first_key"'):]
                        yield data2
        except:
                data = ""
                flag = 1
                continue
```